# xml sub node search

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml file with address and it works fine.
I want the xml file to be searched with State. Kindly help me please.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#INFO').click(function() {
        $.get('book.xml',function(book){
            $('#content').empty();
            $(book).find('data').each(function(){
                var $data= $(this);
                var html = '<div class="book">';    
                html += '<b> M/s.: ' + $data.attr('company') + '</b> ';
                html += '<div class="address">' + $data.find('address').text() + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="address1">' + $data.find('address1').text() + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="state">' + $data.find('state').text() + '&nbsp;&nbsp; Pincode:' +$data.find('pin').text() + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="phone"> Phone:' + $data.find('phone').text() + '</div>';
                $('#content').append(html);
            });                        
        });
        return false;
    });
});

    <body>
    <a href="#" id="INFO">Get Full address</a>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div id="content">
    </div></body>
```

Sir, As asked, the XML file for Book.xml is given below. 
What I require is seraching the address with "state== Maharashtra"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datas>
    <data company="Bhusan Limited">
        <address> Main road, Second lane, </address>    
       <address1>MUMBAI </address1>
       <state> Maharastra </state>    
        <pin>400020</pin>
        <phone>022-23452345 </phone>
    </data>
```

Comment: Show the XML file. What exactly doesn't work? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(book).find('data')...` try this:

```
$($.parseXML(book)).find('data')...
```